# Como agrego el metodo de busqueda en un controlador de Visual Basic .net

Tags: html, visual-studio, entity-framework

Tengo esto en el index de mi clase productos en este tengo variables como nombre precio descripcion y categoria

```
<p>

    Que deseas buscar: <input type="search" name="busqueda">

    <input type="submit" value="Buscar">

</p>
```

Pero no se como agregar el metodo de busqueda este es mi controlador vi varias opciones pero la mayoria son en C#

```
    Private db As New bdVentasEntities

    ' GET: Productoes
    Function Index() As ActionResult
        Dim producto = db.Producto.Include(Function(p) p.Categoria)
        Return View(producto.ToList())
    End Function

    ' GET: Productoes/Details/5
    Function Details(ByVal id As Integer?) As ActionResult
        If IsNothing(id) Then
            Return New HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
        End If
        Dim producto As Producto = db.Producto.Find(id)
        If IsNothing(producto) Then
            Return HttpNotFound()
        End If
        Return View(producto)
    End Function
```

Comment: Pero cual es el problema???

Comment: No se cual es el metodo que debo agregar para que el buscador funcione, estuve intentado modificar el index pero no me salio 
Function Index() As ActionResult
            Dim producto = db.Producto.Include(Function(p) p.Categoria)
            Return View(producto.ToList())
        End Function